# How to expose client_address to all methods, using xmlrpclib?

Tags: python, xmlrpclib

I create little SimpleXMLRPCServer for check ip of client.

I try this:

## Server

import xmlrpclib

from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer

server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("localhost", 8000))

def MyIp():
    return "Your ip is: %s" % server.socket.getpeername()

server.register_function(MyIp)

server.serve_forever()

## Client

import xmlrpclib

se = xmlrpclib.Server("http://localhost:8000")

print se.MyIp()

## Error

xmlrpclib.Fault: :(107, 'Transport endpoint is not connected')">

How make client_address visible to all functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want for example to pass `client_address` as the first argument to every function, you could subclass SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler (pass your subclass as the handler when you instantiate SimpleXMLRPCServer) and override `_dispatch` (to prepend `self.client_address` to the params tuple and then delegate the rest to `SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler._dispatch`). If this approach is OK and you want to see code, just ask!

I'm not sure how you'd safely use anything but the function arguments to "make `client_address` visible" -- there's no `client_address` as a bare name, global or otherwise, there's just the `self.client_address` of each instance of the request handler class (and hacks such as copying it to a global variables feel *really* yucky indeed -- and unsafe under threading, etc etc).

Comment: I am using the same approach. Subclass of SimpleXMLRPCRequestHandler and appending client_address to parameters of calling function.